# Trigger event on an injected element in the DOM in React

Tags: reactjs

We have a project where some markup gets injected into our platform from a chatbot. The HTML element is on the page and we are able to style it using CSS, so it is definitely part of the DOM and not embedded as an iFrame or something funny.

We need to manually trigger an event when one of the controls of the chatbot is clicked. I know this is possible to do with something like jQuery, but I am struggling to find a way of doing so in React.js.

Can you select an element from the Dom and trigger an event on it in React? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we have found a solution to this:

```
useEffect(() => {​​​​​​​​ 
  let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("class_of_element");
  if(btns && btns.length){​​​​​​​​
    btns[0].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }​​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​​);

const handleClick = () => {​​​​​​​​
  console.log("working")
}​​​​​​​​
```